# openGL GL_STATIC_DRAW vs GL_STATIC_READ performance

Tags: opengl, jogl

Using this initialisation block:

```
public void init(GL gl) {
      buffer = new int[1];
      gl.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);

     VBOVertices = buffer[0];
     gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertices);
     gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.limit() * BufferUtil.SIZEOF_FLOAT, vertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
     gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

     init = true;

}
```

And this rendering block:

```
public void display(GL gl) {
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE);
    gl.glBlendEquation(GL.GL_FUNC_ADD);

    gl.glDepthMask(false);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertices);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL.GL_FLOAT, 7 * 4, 3 * 4);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 7 * 4, 0);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, vertices.limit() / 7);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

}
```

I get a serious performance penalty on some graphics cards (GeForce GT 750M) that disappears when I change GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW to GL.GL_STATIC_READ, and I do not understand why.
I have tried to use padding for the vertices, but that didn't change anything. Can somebody explain this behaviour?

Comment: Well, `STATIC_DRAW` would be the correct usage hint for this scenario. What kind of "seriuos performance penalty" do we speak of, here?

Comment: The framerate is dropping from 30fps to 5fps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_STATIC_READ` is an odd hint, because it's basically saying "I'm going to read from this buffer on the CPU a lot, but only going to write into once (or a few times)", so it's use in glBufferData is dubious.  It would typically indicate that you're going to copy data out of *another* buffer into it.  The most obvious behavior from a GL client implementation would be to allocate such a buffer in system memory, NOT on the GPU.

The implication of this would be that for some reason your video card is performing better reading the data out of system memory than GPU dedicated memory.  There could be any number of reasons for that, such as GPU memory congestion, alignment issues, driver bugs, etc.

Of course you may be able to get more information by enabling some GL debugging features and setting up the debug callbacks.  Often times drivers will let you know when you're doing something that's killing performance through these callbacks.  It might be something else completely that's only being exposed through this quirk.